# Why do I have a space between button 1 and button2?

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, tkinter-layout

I set up a grid system with a top frame and a bottom frame. The top frame has buttons on the east side and they should be uniform with each other but I seem to have messed up somewhere because there is a gap between button 1 and button 2. Any feedback would be great. I am trying to geta head start on my final project for Computer Science 2.

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry("1000x600+0+0")
        self.title('Amazon Scraper')
        self.resizable(True,True)

        # configure the grid
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=5)
        self.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(1,weight=3)

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        search=tk.StringVar()
        filter_search= tk.StringVar()
        
        topFrame=tk.Frame(self, bg='red')
        topFrame.columnconfigure(0,weight=3)
        topFrame.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        topFrame.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='nesw')
        
        tabControl = ttk.Notebook(topFrame)
        tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
        tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl)
        tabControl.add(tab1, text ='Search')
        tabControl.add(tab2, text ='Filter')
        tabControl.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=1, sticky='nesw')
        
        label1=tk.Label(tab1, text="Search").grid(column=0,row=0, sticky='nesw', padx=2,pady=2)
        label2=tk.Label(tab2, text="Filter").grid(column=0, row=0,sticky='nesw',padx=2,pady=2)

        entry1=tk.Entry(tab1, width=30,bg='light blue', textvariable=search).grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='nesw',padx=2,pady=2)
        entry2=tk.Entry(tab2, width=30,bg='light blue', textvariable=filter_search).grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='nesw',padx=2,pady=2)

        btn1=tk.Button(topFrame, text='Button 1', bg='light blue').grid(column=1,row=0,sticky='ne',padx=2,pady=1)
        btn2=tk.Button(topFrame, text='Button 2', bg='light blue').grid(column=1,row=1,sticky='ne',padx=2,pady=1)
        btn3=tk.Button(topFrame, text='Button 3', bg='light blue').grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='ne',padx=2,pady=1)
        btn4=tk.Button(topFrame, text='Button 4', bg='light blue').grid(column=1,row=3,sticky='ne',padx=2,pady=1)

        bottomeFrame=tk.Frame(self, bg='green')
        bottomeFrame.columnconfigure(0,weight=3)
        bottomeFrame.grid(column=0,row=1,stick='nesw')
        
        for i in range(5):
            label5=tk.Label(bottomeFrame, text=f'{i}: Label', bg='light blue').grid(column=0,row=i, columnspan=2, sticky='nesw')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Oh, and the background color is just to distinguish the frames from each other.

[image]

Comment: Row 0 of `topFrame` contains both `btn1` and `tabControl`.  The taller of the two sets the row height.  Perhaps `tabControl` should have a `rowspan=` so that its height can be spread over multiple of the Button rows, or perhaps it should be someplace else entirely in the widget hierarchy so that it isn't competing with the Buttons.

Comment: Wow that makes perfect sense now. I will re-work it. Play around with the rowspan or put them in seperate frames. Thank you

Comment: rowspan worked perfect

Comment: @davidrose071783, Please answer your own question when the code gets fixed in comments, other people come here and their time gets wasted

Answer (score 0):

@jasonharper

rowspan is exactly what I needed thank you

```
tabControl.grid(column=0,row=0, rowspan=8, sticky='nesw')
```